# Word or phrase for premeditated act of self defense

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Consider a scenario where a person is forced to act and attack a person who they consider to be a threat even though there has been no display of such threat. I am talking about sensing danger and acting upon it.

This doesn't sound like *self-defence*. As usually, self defence is the use of physical force to counter an **immediate** threat of violence. [OxfordDictionaries.com](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/self-defence) defines it as:

> the defence of one’s person or interests, especially through the use of physical force, which is permitted in certain cases as an answer to a charge of violent crime.

*I am looking for a word or phrase that would describe an act of premeditated self-defence, in **anticipation** of a threat.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is normally called a [***pre-emptive*** strike](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pre-emptive?q=pre-emptive).

> *adjective*
>      serving or intended to pre-empt or forestall something, especially to prevent attack by disabling the enemy:
>   *a pre-emptive strike*

Comment: I think thats the word!

Comment: That used to be the word when I was a boy, but now it's been replaced by the more fashionable _proactive_, even in my semi-petrified memory banks. Thank you for reminding me of its existence. Still a very good word.

Comment: I've never heard *proactive* used in respect of dealing with a physical threat. It is used to describe forestalling a fault occurring in a system, though.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase *anticipatory self-defense* has been used in international law since the 1837 [*Caroline* Affair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caroline_affair) between the United States and Britian:

> This incident has been used to establish the principle of "anticipatory self-defense" in international politics, which holds that it may be justified only in cases in which the "necessity of that self-defense is instant, overwhelming, and leaving no choice of means, and no moment for deliberation".

Comment: Thats a really interesting point! Depending upon context, this too might be a suitable choice.

Answer (score 1):

The current term for this kind of anticipatory [strike](http://www.examiner.com/article/neighborhood-watch-makes-proactive-strike) is *[proactive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proactive)*.

Comment: I'd use *proactive* to refer to arming yourself, or getting a better lock on your door, but *pre-emptive* only for actually attacking the perceived threat.